# UserProfile rest API

Tags: javascript, user-profile, rest, user-profile-service

I need to retrieve **User Profile information by REST**.
I am using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var requestUri = "http://mySite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='myDom\user123'";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

I always have a **NULL result** (on success).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The account name should be `encodeURIComponent`.

```
var accountname = 'myDom\user123';
var requestUri = "http://mySite/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'";
```

The same task can be done in a different way as below

```
var theData = {
 "propertiesForUser": {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" }, 
    "accountName": "i:0#.f|membership|vardhaman@tsunami684.onmicrosoft.com",
    "propertyNames": ["PreferredName", "Department"]
     }
};

var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertiesFor",
    type:"POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        console.log(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

[Source](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: If i need all the properties? I need a properties to see if the user is active on user profile

Comment: Check the source link i provided. I has a list of available properties.